# two classes, one page, 2nd class dies before instantiation

Tags: php, class

How can I code a page to call two classes that go to the same db, then parse the results separately? If I try

```
require_once('class1.php');
$api = new api(array(
'query' => 'foo',
));
$results = $api->fetch();
foreach
```

these results are parsed, but if I then try later on the same page

```
require_once('class2.php');    
$api = new api(array(
'query' => 'bar',
));
$results = $api->fetch();
foreach
```

it will die before instantiation.

Comment: Any error messages / anything that can help us debug?

Comment: You must have errors off.  Just a guess, but you might be declaring the same class twice, which results in a fatal error.

Comment: A class cannot be named "class". I wonder how it could work in the first place.

Comment: no error, it just dies. they are not named class. I'm going to edit to clear up any confusion.

Comment: By dies you mean it just stopped executing after the second $api = new api()? Can you do try adding this on the first line of the script: ini_set("error_reporting", E_ALL);

Comment: thanks andreas! - it is a fatal error. "Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class API in /home". I'm going to check with the dev and see if I can rename the class.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior happens when there's a syntax error inside your class. It can be in your function, in your constructor, or in a definition. For whatever reason, some versions of PHP don't catch this, so instead of alerting the user of the syntax error, PHP just stops running.